# What is meant by the rel="bookmark" link attribute?

Tags: html, seo, anchor

What is the purpose of the `rel="bookmark"` attribute in `<a>` tags? For example:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" rel="bookmark">Click Here</a>
```

Does it serve any SEO- or SEM-related purpose?

Comment: Just a way to define link relationships. Sometimes when I develop web applications with jQuery and Javascript I look for a certain rel value to tell me when to do stuff. Other than that, I don't know.

Comment: *(reference)* **for HTML5** : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#link-type-bookmark **previous versions** : http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.12

Comment: Why this question is flagged as off topic?

Answer (score 29):

This has no SEO value or purpose. I believe the rel=bookmark tag was intended to mark [permalinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink) but it never really gained traction

Answer (score 26):

An important use of the LINK element is to define a toolbar of navigation buttons or an equivalent mechanism such as menu items.

LINK relationship values reserved for toolbars are:

REL=Home
    The link references a home page or the top of some hierarchy.

REL=ToC
    The link references a document serving as a table of contents.

REL=Index
    The link references a document providing an index for the current document.

REL=Glossary
    The link references a document providing a glossary of terms that pertain to the current document.

REL=Copyright
    The link references a copyright statement for the current document.

REL=Up
    When the document forms part of a hierarchy, this link references the immediate parent of the current document.

REL=Next
    The link references the next document to visit in a guided tour.

REL=Previous
    The link references the previous document in a guided tour.

REL=Help
    The link references a document offering help, e.g. describing the wider context and offering further links to relevant documents. This is aimed at reorienting users who have lost their way.

REL=Bookmark
    Bookmarks are used to provide direct links to key entry points into an extended document. The TITLE attribute may be used to label the bookmark. Several bookmarks may be defined in each document, and provide a means for orienting users in extended documents.

From: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/dochead.html

Comment: The question was about rel=bookmark in the context of the "a" tag. Isn't the "link" tag a separate thing?

Answer (score 15):

The attribute "rel" means relationship. It's a microformats. The HTML4 spec describes a bookmark as "a link to a key entry point within an extended document". By convention (citation needed), this entry point also captures the notion of a "permalink". Exemple:

```
<a href="archive/entry.html" rel="bookmark">A Document Entry</a>
```

Another exemple of rel attribute for tags:

```
<a href="http://technorati.com/tag/tech" rel="tag">tech</a>
```

http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-bookmark#rel.3D.22bookmark.22