# Is it possible to provide a specific URL to be used for anyone bookmarking a page within a web application?

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarks

I have a scenario where users are adding bookmarks to pages within a web application which are time/session specific. Any user who visits a bookmark is automatically redirected to login but they are then redirected to the "invalid session page" and taken back to the homepage.

Is it possible for me to add something into my mark-up or a script which can tell the browser a specific link address to use at anytime inside the web application which would basically strip off any parameters from the URL before saving it.

I did find this meta tag `<link rel='bookmark'title='Google' href='http://google.com/'>` but as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803505/what-is-meant-by-the-rel-bookmark-link-attribute) explains, that is not going to help me.

Comment: This should be configured at the web server.

Answer (score -2):

No, this is not possible.

Instead, redesign your URLs so that they are not session-specific. Get rid of sessions entirely, other than for login purposes. In a modern web site, the most that should happen if the user comes back after a long time is that they see a login page before getting right back to where they were.

If this sounds impractical to implement, I suggest you ask a question describing what information you're keeping in session state and how to change that.

Generally, **depending on the type of information**, it should be stored either:

- in your data store, associated with the *user*, not session (for substantial user-specific things like “the draft post I'm writing”),
- in the URL itself (for all “what view am I looking at” info), or
- in browser storage (cookies, `localStorage`, etc.; **not preferred** because the user may delete it across all sites or change browsers).

Comment: Cookies and localStorage are equivalent to sessions and also expire, you should not rely on it for application states. Application state should be preserved through the URL. User object isn't also for application state, user object is mostly for user preferences, settings, etc.

Comment: @DanielAranda They don't *expire*, they *can be deleted*. I added a bit more on the specifics and warned about that, but I'm not here to write an epic on proper REST, just to give some broad advice on where to look instead and what the next question to ask should be.

Comment: Thank you. I use MVC and don't use any sessions as such and all data is stored in a database, but as an example, data would be processed (or published) on the server and assigned an ID.  When someone then adds a bookmark, that ID is contained in the URL but once that data is reprocessed it is given a new ID creating an invalid URL. I was really hoping there would be a way to remove these URL parameters so that people can't keep hitting invalid, expired ID's.

Comment: @wf4 You can always change the “expired ID” response of your server to be a page which is helpful. Better yet, instead of the ID of the output put the ID of the *input* in the URL, which can be used to locate the new version and serve that!